# How to allow only one method in an application made with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, limit, restriction

I made a contest where members could register to win prizes. 
Now, it's time to display results and winners of the contest. I want to allow only one controller and one method, to disable the possibility to still register to the contest.

I think redirections may be a great solution but how to do this on the whole application without copy and paste the code in every methods of each controller?

Any ideas/advices welcomed!

Comment: I would have a contests table in DB... this way you can set a isOpen flag or something and check the status of the contest from within any page you may want to check if a specific contest is still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to catch any url in your routes file (`config/routes.php`) and assign it to the controller action you want to show:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller';
$route['(:any)'] = "controller/action";
```

This is also faster than using redirects.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the controller, you can add a check to see if the user is calling a specific function or not by matching `uri_string()` to your required method's `uri`, and then redirect him using `redirect()`. This is effective because, a check in controller's constructor means, the user doesn't even have access to the methods when the check happens. So there is no way he/she can execute them.

EDIT: It works.

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    if(uri_string() !== "controller_name/allowed_method_name"){
        redirect("/"); // some where
    }
}
```